# access denied when accessing couchdb from laptop over ethernet cable

Tags: linux, couchdb-futon

I have a raspberry pi with couchdb on it, Raspberry pi connected to laptop via Ethernet cable and i Can ssh to raspberry pi using Putty no problem. However I cannot access fauxton via ipaddress:5984/_utils/index.html

I have set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 in the local.ini file, that did not work, I then checked the config in fauxton and it was still local host, so I changed that to 0.0.0.0 then rebooted the raspberry pi. Connected again via Putty, but still get access denied when trying to access couchdb remotely.

As far as I am aware, raspberry pi does not have a firewall enabled by default and I have not set one up. I think I am missing a major point somewhere. Where should I be looking next to resolve this issue?

Edit: So it appears that I can ssh in to the Raspberry pi itself, on port 22, however I can't ssh on port 5984 it comes back with "Server unexpectedly closed network connection". So is the host the Raspberry pi I am ssh to or is it the Windows computer that I ssh from?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved this, it was the firewall on my work computer. As soon as I connected to another Raspberry pi, it connected straight away.